# shell scripting works with 'bash' but not with 'sh'

Tags: scripts

```
#!bin/bash
NAME[0]="KANNA"
echo "first name: ${NAME[0]}"
```

The above script is executed with `bash filename` but not with `sh filename`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array is not supported in bourne shell (sh). For more information about this check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481702/how-to-make-an-array-in-shell) on stack overflow. For more information about array in bash check following links

1. [TLDP](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html)
2. [GNU](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need `#!/bin/bash` (note the extra `/`) and you'll need to `chmod +x filename.sh` if you want to execute it.